# Jacoco integration with WebSphere

Tags: jacoco

I m trying to integrate Jacoco with Websphere to get the code coverage by Manual Testing.
I have set JVM arguments as below

```
![-javaagent:C:\Shankara\Software\jacoco-0.7.2.201409121644\lib\jacocoagent.jar=destfile=C:\Shankara\Software\jacoco.exec,append=true,includes=com.*][1]
```

i m able to get exec file successfully however the coverage is still red colour. Please assists me on this urgently

Comment: Did you stop the target JVM instance. Until you do that, you won't get the code coverage data (of source main code) via running your non-unit tests. Do this: 1. Attach jacocoagent.jar and pass params (like you have done) then 2. Run your tests (manual / automated which will exercise / cover the main source code), then 3. Stop the target JVM instance/session (which is WebSphere), then 4. You'll notice jacoco file size will be a little more than what you're getting before. Use this jacoco exec for running jacocoTestReport to get the final code coverage.

Comment: Hi All, Thank you. I m able to get exec file, However when i open this file in eclipse, The coverage is not clear, Everything is not covered.

Comment: WIth this, are you running websphere in an IDE or is it a stand alone server? I need jacoco to work with a stand alone server/

Answer (score 1):

Did you stop the target JVM instance.

Until you do that, you won't get the code coverage data (of source main code) via running your non-unit tests.

Try this:
 
1. Attach jacocoagent.jar and pass params (like you have done) then 
2. Run your tests (manual / automated which will exercise / cover the main source code), then 
3. Stop the target JVM instance/session (which is WebSphere), then 
4. You'll notice jacoco file size will be a little more than what you're getting before.

Use this jacoco exec (which you get after stopping the target JVM instance) for running jacocoTestReport to get the final code coverage %.

Note: If you don't want to stop the target JVM session/instance where your application/webservice is running then read Jacoco documentation as there's a way to do that too.

See here: http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html
Specially the parameters:

**dumponexit**  If set to true coverage data will be written on VM shutdown. The dump can only be written if either file is specified or the output is tcpserver/tcpclient and a connection is open at the time when the VM terminates.     true

**output**  Output method to use for writing coverage data. Valid options are:

```
file: At VM termination execution data is written to the file specified in the destfile attribute.
tcpserver: The agent listens for incoming connections on the TCP port specified by the address and port attribute. Execution data is written to this TCP connection.
tcpclient: At startup the agent connects to the TCP port specified by the address and port attribute. Execution data is written to this TCP connection.
none: Do not produce any output.
```

Please see the security considerations below.

**address**     IP address or hostname to bind to when the output method is tcpserver or connect to when the output method is tcpclient. In tcpserver mode the value "*" causes the agent to accept connections on any local address.   loopback interface

**port**    Port to bind to when the output method is tcpserver or connect to when the output method is tcpclient. In tcpserver mode the port must be available, which means that if multiple JaCoCo agents should run on the same machine, different ports have to be specified.

Comment: Hi Arun, thank you for your inputs. Now i m able to see jacoco.exec with some data. But when i import in eclipse i dont see covered codes. When i see executes class i m able to see those classes.. Could you please advise

Comment: What values are you using for Jacoco main source code and test code in Eclipse?

Comment: I m using main source code. By the way what do u mean by test code.

Comment: Jacoco uses tests (unit/non-unit type) which runs/hits the main source-code class files and instruments it on the fly. You try to get code coverage of your main source code to see how much you are covering using your tests. Jacoco has values where you specify where's my main source code (src/main/java etc) and where are your tests source code is i.e. src/test/java, src/integrationTest/java etc. If you have populated that, then all you need to make sure is, for generating IT tests  coverage, start tomcat, run tests, stop tomcat and only then jacocoIT.exec file will be populated fully.

Comment: Hi Arun, thank you for input. Basically mine is web app and deployed inside websphere i build manually and installed after that i hit my app url and did some login, query and logout. It does not invoke any test code it will invoke main code.. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It'll invoke main classes/code. Now, how are you doing the tests/running them. As you mentioned hit URL, login this and that, are you using an automated way to test the login page, enter user/password, check a button/click around here and there and all that via some testing Framework (like Selenium GUI browser based tests)? If you are using tests either manual/automated way, you test code get you the coverage of your main source code (running behind Websphere). There's a way in jacoco (when you pass jacoco arguments destfile=... and etc) where you can tell it as tcpserver.

Comment: I m not invoking any test code (unit) I m directly hitting my main code. I code see Jacoco.exec with some bytes and when I import to eclipse the code coverage is zero and I can see my class in executed classes

Comment: You get code coverage of main code using/after running test code (unit or non-unit tests).

Comment: I am just wondering, how do you attach jacoco to websphere? I am currently trying to start this.

Comment: Hi all, Thank you very much.. I got required output.. By generating the coverage report using ant task after my ft completion...